# Why do library implementer use short names?

Tags: c++, performance, naming-conventions, libraries

This is a naive question , but why are all the function and variable names in libraries so short ?

For example in lapack.cpp a name of a function is

```
dgetrs
```

look at this site 
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/d49/dgetrs_8f.html

All the functions are named in the same short manner.

Is there any performance cost to having larger names ?

From my view point , using short names causes so many problems, it makes it difficult to understand code. Debugging becomes difficult. Many things can be conveyed by a good function name , why are library developers giving it up ? 
I realize that the people who write the libraries are much more experienced than I am , so I would like to know the reason.

Typing becomes slightly easier , but isn't that compensated by usability and maintainability over the long run ?

Comment: The only performance cost is in the compiler/interpreter. Supposedly old versions of FORTRAN had a length limit of only 6 characters.

Comment: @Lalaland that makes sense. Is there such a cost for the newer (comparatively )languages like C++ ? -thanks

Comment: @Lalaland, that doesn't explain why the standard C library has `strcpy`, `strlen`, etc.

Comment: @nnrales There is always a cost for the compiler. Modern computers are simply fast enough for it not to matter. For a more modern length limit, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc2y4ddf(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: @Lalaland there are so many things to know !

Comment: I believe that for C89, the variable name limit was 6 for external identifiers.  So `strcpy`, `strcmp`, etc. had to be used.

Comment: @nnrales Oh, and to actually answer your question, short names are a bad idea. Libraries originally used them due to laziness or ancient limited compilers, and then were stuck supporting them for backwards compatibility reasons. Use long enough names to express your intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Dennis Ritchie set a goal that C shouldn't demand any more from a linker than Fortran.
2. Until Bjarne Stroustrup started a campaign for longer identifiers, linkers typically had rather short limits on names.

So C for example suffers from library names like `strcpy()` for precisely this reason. It ceased to be an issue by the late 1980s, but the habit seems to persist.